# How to deal with jQuery bootgrid request data in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, jquery-bootgrid

I'm having some issues with implementing a jQuery bootgrid using ASP.Net MVC. I can't implement the sorting, searching, pagination etc. functionality.

This is what I have in my controller:

```
public JsonResult IndexJson(BootgridRequestData model)
{
    var contacts = (from x in db.ContactSet
                    select new
                    {
                        x.AccountId,
                        x.FirstName,
                        x.LastName,
                        x.FullName,
                        x.JobTitle,
                        x.ParentCustomerId,
                        x.EMailAddress1,
                        x.Telephone1,
                        x.MobilePhone,
                        x.Fax,
                        x.GenderCode,
                        x.BirthDate
                    }).ToList();

    // This tResult throws a Non-invocable member cannot be used like a method error. 
    var tResult = BootgridResponseData<JsonResult>() {
        current = model.current,
        rowCount = model.rowCount,
        rows = contacts,
        total = contacts.Count
    };

    return Json(tResult, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Then I have the following helper classes:

```
public class BootgridRequestData
{
    public int current { get; set; }
    public string rowCount { get; set; }
    public string searchPhrase { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<SortData> sortItems { get; set; }
}

public class BootgridResponseData<T> where T : class
{
    public int current { get; set; } //? current page
    public int rowCount { get; set; } //? rows per page
    public IEnumerable<T> rows { get; set; } //? items
    public int total { get; set; } //? total rows for whole query
}

public class SortData
{
    public string Field { get; set; } //? Field Name
    public string Type { get; set; } //? ASC or DESC
}
```

I'm not really too sure where to go from here. Any advice?

Comment: hey man how are you utilizing the BootgridRequestData model in your razor page. Would you mind throwing an example up somewhere I haven't been able to get what I thought would work actually working. looking for a little guidance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template `T` needs to be the same object type of your list.

```
public class BootgridResponseData<T> where T : class
{
    public int current { get; set; } //? current page
    public int rowCount { get; set; } //? rows per page
    public IEnumerable<T> rows { get; set; } //? items
    public int total { get; set; } //? total rows for whole query
}
```

In your case your list its being generated as `List<object>`. It would be nice if you create a new type like(im assuming all the ids are strings, adapt it at your needs, `Guid`, `int` etc):

```
public class Contact
{
    public string AccountId {get; set;}
    public string FirstName {get; set;}
    public string LastName {get; set;}
    public string FullName {get; set;}
    public string JobTitle {get; set;}
    public string ParentCustomerId {get; set;}
    public string EMailAddress1 {get; set;}
    public string Telephone1 {get; set;}
    public string MobilePhone {get; set;}
    public string Fax {get; set;}
    public string GenderCode {get; set;}
    public DateTime BirthDate {get; set;}
}
```

and Instead of this

```
select new
{
    x.AccountId,
    x.FirstName,
    x.LastName,
    x.FullName,
    x.JobTitle,
    x.ParentCustomerId,
    x.EMailAddress1,
    x.Telephone1,
    x.MobilePhone,
    x.Fax,
    x.GenderCode,
    x.BirthDate
}
```

i would put this

```
select new Contact
{
    AccountId = x.AccountId,
    FirstName = x.FirstName,
    LastName = x.LastName,
    FullName = x.FullName,
    JobTitle = x.JobTitle,
    ParentCustomerId = x.ParentCustomerId,
    EMailAddress1 = x.EMailAddress1,
    Telephone1 = x.Telephone1,
    MobilePhone = x.MobilePhone,
    Fax = x.Fax,
    GenderCode = x.GenderCode,
    BirthDate = x.BirthDate
 }
```

and your return will be like this, because your contacts are now of the type `List<Contact>`

```
var tResult = new
          BootgridResponseData<List<Contact>>() 
          {
              current = model.current,
              rowCount = model.rowCount,
              rows = contacts,
              total = contacts.Count
          };
```

In the front end, don't forget to put the table headers.

```
<table id="grid-data" class="table table-condensed table-hover table-striped">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th data-column-id="AccountId">Account ID</th>
            <th data-column-id="FirstName">First Name</th>
            <th data-column-id="LastName">Last Name</th>
            (...) and so on
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

The grid JavaScript in the front end will look like, depending if your function is a web GET or POST, your ajax settings may change.

```
$("#grid-data").bootgrid({
    ajax: true,
    ajaxSettings: {
    method: "GET",
    cache: false
}
    url: "<your_mvc_controller_url>"
});
```

Take a look at [bootgrid official page examples](http://www.jquery-bootgrid.com/Examples#data)

Comment: I get the following error at my `var tResult = ...`:  `Non-invocable member 'BootgridResponseData<T>' cannot be used like a method.`

Comment: Take a look at my GitHub Repository

 https://github.com/bmvr/MVC_BOOTGRID_EXAMPLE/tree/master/MVC_Bootgrid_example) with this example.

once you run the code, go to the url <your_localhost>/Example/

Try to adapt this at your needs.

Comment: It was missing the `new` keyword :/

Comment: Oh yeah, you're right! Sorry i'll update my answer then.

Comment: Thanks for the help...  Now to solve my `NullException` error :P